# Please Help explain a solution in a Geometric distribution problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

someone please explain to me the solution for this
Assuming that each student visits 5 booths during a typical career fair, find the probability that an A student in 313 will not get an off-campus interview invitation. Similarly,
find the probability that a C student in 313 will get an invitation during a typical career
fair.

There a solution here (question c: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fa2012/homework/sol04.pdf)
for this question but I don't get it. I don't understand why there is a 6 in the sum if we only have 5 trials

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why there is a 6 in the sum if we only have 5 trials

simply because  you are calculating

$$\mathbb{P}[X>5]=\mathbb{P}[X=6]+\mathbb{P}[X=7]+\mathbb{P}[X=8]+\dots$$

Obvioulsly it is simplier to do

$$(1-p)^5=0.05^5\approx 3\cdot 10^{-7}$$

Answer (score 0):

The event "an A student does not get an invitation in $5$ trials" is the same event as "it takes at least $6$ trials for an A student to get an invitation". The corresponding equation with probabilities is

$$P(X\geq 6)=\underbrace{1-P(X\leq 5)}_{\textrm{Student does not get an invitation in 5 trials}}$$